# How to fix Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() in Wildfly?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-12

We see in our logs a big amount of these errors (1k per second)

> ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-1)
>   javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in
>   managedConnectionReconnected()
>   cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@7cf06c5e[state=NORMAL
>   managed
>   connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@6cecd5f4
>   connection handles=0 lastReturned=1589648691492
>   lastValidated=1589648383871 lastCheckedOut=1589648390322
>   trackByTx=false
>   pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@5755db92
>   mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@7c0f33f2[pool=OAPIDS]
>   xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@458307ec[connectionListener=7cf06c5e
>   connectionManager=180e08c1 warned=false currentXid=null
>   productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.5.14 jndiName=java:/OAPIDS]
>   txSync=null]

Is it signal that the datasource under big load or App server bug, fixed in later versions?

Our App server is Wildfly 12

DB is Postgres

And some of database queries do not work at the same time with errors "Unable to acquire connection"

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@43697861[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@58a27593 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1589649243598 lastValidated=1589648924489 lastCheckedOut=1589649243527 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@5755db92 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@7c0f33f2[pool=OAPIDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@2e150b3f[connectionListener=43697861 connectionManager=180e08c1 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.5.14 jndiName=java:/OAPIDS] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@43697861[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@58a27593 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1589649243598 lastValidated=1589648924489 lastCheckedOut=1589649243527 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@5755db92 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@7c0f33f2[pool=OAPIDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@2e150b3f[connectionListener=43697861 connectionManager=180e08c1 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.5.14 jndiName=java:/OAPIDS] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:975)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:561)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:970)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a8cf9f:1902a63b:5ebfdd0d:c3e3c status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) is not active STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:296)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:554)
    ... 108 more
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find solution? I have similar issue